# apt-cacher won't work: port 3142 blocked, how to open?

Tags: server, client, apt-cacher

After install ubuntu 12.04 in client PC. I try to setup apt-cache server in client PC. But, it doesn't work in ubuntu client.

```
Err http://136.xxx.xxx.x precise/multiverse Sources
  403  Forbidden
```

I try this step:

```
Step 1: sudo apt-get install apt-cacher apache2
Step 2: sudo nano /etc/default/apt-cacher --> already set AUTOSTART = 1
Step 3: sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart
Step 4: open http://server:3142/apt-cacher in browser
    HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden): The server refused to fulfill the request.
```

Here is my `/etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf`:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1087474/

I try to open:

```
wget -q -O- http://www.google.com

<TITLE>Error</TITLE>
<BODY>
<H1>Error</H1>
FW-1 at jeinfw: Access denied.</BODY>

ufw status

Status: inactive
```

[sudo iptables -L](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1094347/)

[netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1094352/)

Comment: It means , you don't have access to it.

Comment: @tijybba:how to make it can accessing the server ?

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem too. To solve this issue you must edit `/etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf` and find the line that has this word: `#allowed_hosts:*`.

After finding the line delete "#" and add your allowed network to use for example:

```
allowed_hosts:192.168.1.0/24
```

save the file (use sudo for saving), restart your server and apt-cacher-server accessible from every allowed client on your network.

Comment: +1, It is the usual solution for this error.